# selenium webdriver - unable to find the element when page is redirected

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have application when clicked login it redirects to a different page and I am trying to click at the element on redirected page after it's loaded completely but still getting an exception

**org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element**

Tried clicking at the element using id, Css but getting the same issue.

`driver.findelement(By.id("abc")).click();`

(before redirect. This click function will redirect the page to a different site)

then trying to click on redirected page

`driver.findElement(By.id("contentLink_1_HeaderStoreLogo_Content")).click()`;

then getting no such element found.

Comment: Have you tried to add a wait before you look for the second element?

Comment: yes tried wait till the redirected page loads

Comment: Tried switch.frame and was able to click the element on redirected page. Thanks          driver.switchTo().frame("framename");

Comment: So you answered your question? If so, post it as the answer and accept it so others don't spend time researching answers.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem, and the below article helped me resolve it.
https://chercher.tech/python/windows-selenium-python

Solution : 
I've used the 'current_window_handle' , 'window_handles' to resolved it, follow below steps in orders :

- Use the current_window_handle method, which gives you a GU
  ID(Globally Unique Identifier).

  - `parentWindow = driver.current_window_handle`
- Later when you click on a button and redirected to a new window use 
  current_window_handle and store it in a variable

  - `childWindow = driver.current_window_handle`
- Now, collect all the GU IDs, in order to filter parent from current child window's GU ID.

  - `allWindows = driver.window_handles`

Now, I've used a for loop to go thru all the GU IDs and filter the child GU ID

```
for n in allWindows:
    if(parentWindow != n):
        driver.switch_to_window(n)
        break;
```

Good Luck!