# Redirect page does not load in RSelenium automated browser

Tags: r, web-scraping, automation, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I am trying to navigate to this login page in RSelenium: https://www.tipranks.com/sign-in?redirectTo=%2F. It works fine in a non-automated Chrome or Firefox browser, but in an RSelenium automated browser, it never loads.

Here's a reproducible example with FireFox:

```
webpage <- 'https://www.tipranks.com/sign-in?redirectTo=%2F'
driver <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = 'firefox', port = 4818L)
remDr <- driver[['client']]
remDr$navigate(webpage)
```

And here is Chrome:

```
webpage <- 'https://www.tipranks.com/sign-in?redirectTo=%2F'
driver <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = 'chrome', port = 4818L)
remDr <- driver[['client']]
remDr$navigate(webpage)
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Similar question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251906/selenium-webdriver-unable-to-find-the-element-when-page-is-redirected

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Appears to be a different issue, though. In that case, the redirect page was loading, but it was loading in a new frame and the user couldn't figure out how to interact with the new frame. In my case, the page isn't loading at all.

Comment: My problem appears more similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68505515/login-page-loads-fast-in-regular-browser-never-in-via-rselenium

But I was able to load the site that user was having problems with.